# 17.10 - how to keep display scale setting after reboot/logout?

Tags: gnome, 17.10

I have just upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10. In Unity I was running display scaling 1.25 but I understand that fractional scaling is not available in GNOME. Still, everytime I logout or reboot the setting (200%) is reverted back to 100% causing all kinds of weirdness when logging in and changing scaling after startup applications have launched.

What to do to keep my 200% setting?